# What was the security vulnerability behind Box and Dropbox and what's different now?

Tags: privacy, http, known-vulnerabilities, cloud-computing, referer

Earlier today I received a number of comments saying that my shared links were disabled. I looked around and saw a number of articles explaining what happened, and Dropbox posted an [official statement](https://blog.dropbox.com/2014/05/web-vulnerability-affecting-shared-links/)

> For background, whenever you click on a link in any browser, the site you’re going to learns where you came from by something called a referer header. The referer header was designed to enable websites to better understand traffic sources. This is standard practice implemented across all browsers.
>
> Dropbox users can share links to any file or folder in their Dropbox. Files shared via links are only accessible to people who have the link. However, shared links to documents can be inadvertently disclosed to unintended recipients in the following scenario:
>
> A Dropbox user shares a link to a document that contains a hyperlink to a third-party website.
>
> The user, or an authorized recipient of the link, clicks on a hyperlink in the document.
>
> At that point, the referer header discloses the original shared link to the third-party website.
>
> Someone with access to that header, such as the webmaster of the third-party website, could then access the link to the shared document.

Personally, I am not too clear what the vulnerability is, as I've always been under the assumption that a shared link is basically a public link, since I never actually specified WHO has access to it. For example, on Google Drive I can choose who has access to it, regardless whether they have the link or not.

The next paragraph in their statement says that they have patched the vulnerability. How was this done? It looks like if someone managed to get ahold of your shared link, they're still going to have full access to it. At least, when I created new links to my shared folder, I didn't see anything different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header is a HTTP request header that is sent by the browser whenever you navigate to a different page - the URL of the page that contained the link you clicked is sent to the new page within this header (even if it is a different domain).

The referer isn't sent if you type in a URL, and it is not sent by most browsers if your current page is protected by TLS (`https://`).

[This page](http://www.whatismyreferer.com/) can be used to find out if you referer is leaked to it, but this of course will depend on where you link to it from.

The Dropbox vulnerability is when a file is shared via the web and a public URL is generated. This URL is in the form `https://www.example.com/s/123456qwerty/file.htm`, where `123456qwerty` appears to be a randomly generated token.

Normally these links only present a download link to the file, but you can modify the URL from `https://www.dropbox.com/s/...` to `https://dl.dropbox.com/s/...` which will then become `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/...` and would present the HTML file as being served from this domain. Also, the protocol can be changed to `http` which would disable the protection of the referer normally enabled by using the https protocol.

If you share this `dl` link with somebody, and the HTML file contains links to 3rd parties, the `referer` could be sent to the third party when links are clicked, exposing your private share URL with the third party. They would be able to view the `referer` header in their server logs or site analytics reports. This has also caused a second problem when users enter the generated links in a search engine instead of the browser's address bar, as when ads are displayed the [PPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_per_click) report to the advertiser shows the search term that was used, which happens to be the "private" URL to the file.

I'm not sure what the official fix is, bar the temporary deactivation of some shared links (although I haven't been notified of any disabled on my account). [Computer Weekly reports](http://www.computerweekly.com/news/2240220216/Dropbox-finally-fixes-security-vulnerability):-

> Dropbox has now disabled access to links that have been previously shared and implemented a patch to prevent shared links from being exposed from now on.

Possible fixes to this issue could include:

- Parsing of the page to change links such as `http://www.example.com` to use a service such as https://href.li so the link becomes `https://href.li/?http://example.com/` (or more probably, Dropbox's implementation of such a service). This won't work with more complicated links, such as those generated or redirected by JavaScript.
- Parsing of the page to change links to use the [HTML 5 noreferrer tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-noreferrer). This won't work with more complicated links, such as those generated or redirected by JavaScript.
- Force HTTPS for all shared HTML pages. This won't work on all browsers.
- Make HTML pages downloadable only instead of displayed inline - this could break some user setups though if they are using Dropbox as a static file server rather than simply sharing.
- An auth cookie generated when a shared link is followed by the original recipient. This would set the cookie and then redirect to a new URL. e.g. `https://www.example.com/s/123456qwerty/file.htm` sets the cookie then redirects to `https://www.example.com/s/auth/zxcvbn76543/file.htm` which is only accessible if the auth cookie is present. This would make any leaked referer data useless as the URL can only be used in combination with the cookie. This would break any bookmarking of the shared links though, unless the original link was saved manually.
- Setting a [`referrer-policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header to prevent the referer from being leaked in [supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy).

You could test the final fix (whatever that may be) by this linking to [a site](http://www.whatismyreferer.com/) from a shared Dropbox HTML file, checking the `referer` and finding out if you get the same result as the [hidden version](https://href.li/?http://www.whatismyreferer.com/). At the moment of writing, these are still being sent by my Dropbox shared HTML page when accessed over http.

### Update

> The next paragraph in their statement says that they have patched the vulnerability. How was this done? It looks like if someone managed to get ahold of your shared link, they're still going to have full access to it. At least, when I created new links to my shared folder, I didn't see anything different.

Only recently have Dropbox added [Passwords for Shared Links](https://www.dropbox.com/help/5887) and [Shared Link Expiration](https://www.dropbox.com/help/5888) to their Pro accounts only.

> If you’re a Dropbox Pro or Dropbox for Business user, you can set a password for any shared link that you create. This helps to ensure that only collaborators with the password can access your shared content.
>
> If you’re a Dropbox Pro or Dropbox for Business user, you can set an expiration for any shared link that you create. This enables you to provide temporary access to content that you want to share.

These two features help resolve the vulnerability of files being accessible due to `referer` or PPC reports.

### Update 2

As per https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/public-folder:

> As of September 1, 2017 public links have been disabled for all users.

Answer (score 2):

The `referer` is an identifer passed in the HTTP header saying where you came from. For example, if you do a search in search engine the site you land at can determine from this field that you came from the search engine and did not type the URL directly.

Shared links are just out there, but you need to know they exist or guess them - but there is nothing really stopping you from accessing the shared link because they are designed to be open. This is **security by obscurity**, and not a real protection.

So when you post the link on page, and someone clicks the link, the referral information can be exposed. The referral information is not required to be passed. Using H[TTPS for the links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033300/stop-link-from-sending-referrer-to-destination) is one method to prevent sending the referer information, Google does something similar to hide specific referer details for logged on users. There are also some [HTML5 and other proposals](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/When+does+your+browser+send+a+%22Referer%22+header+%28or+not%29?/16433). You could also redirect all links through an exit-gateway instead of linking directly to a third party resource. e.g., if the document contains a link to `http://www.somesite.com` you replace the underlying link with `http://www.filesharingsite.com/out.php?site=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somesite.com` then `filesharingsite.com` does a redirect so the referer information no longer points to the source document, but only to the exit page. On a personal level, you can use browser plugins and privacy proxies to help prevent this header information from being sent.

I am not a Dropbox user and I haven't seen them post any specific details on what methods they are using yet.

> A Dropbox user shares a link to a document that contains a hyperlink to a third-party website.

What this means is that there is a Dropbox document link with a hyperlink embeded that points to another site, the referral information not only says "Dropbox" but a identifier which could be linked to a specific document id. If you have logs, you can go through the referer entries and identify these document ids, then go to the shared document which is obscured rather than hidden.

You can learn more about the discovery of the attack in the [Intralink's blog](http://collaboristablog.com/2014/05/sensitive-information-risk-file-sync-share-security-issue/) (the company who made the recent public disclosure)

Comment: I found a exit-link script on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428762/hide-referrer-on-click/11249553#11249553