# Is using "Signature Versioning" in Amazon S3 a secure way of selling ebooks?

Tags: brute-force, url

I own an ecommerce platform that sells large (500 megabyte+) ebooks. To reduce server costs I am looking at hosting the ebooks on S3 and using Sendowl/ FetchApp to create the links to the downloads.

My understanding is that "customer buys ebook" -> "customer receives signed url (i.e. `example.com/ksljfasdkfj`)" -> signed URL goes to actual s3 file (i.e. `amazon.bucket/file1.pdf`)"

Assuming that the middleman I use to sign the domain works correctly, and my bucket file has the correct security settings, is this secure? What is keeping someone from just brute-forcing the file system to find other files or use the link after it expires? My nightmare would be a security hole wherein someone could access all the documents.

Comment: Ultimately, your question isn't about Amazon at all or signing, but about your obscure URL scheme.

Comment: Potential duplicates: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91837/use-of-obscure-url-for-security

Comment: Your concern is about all the *other* stuff besides a brute-forceable URL. And you do not provide any details on how you keep the buckets secure or how you invalidate links once used, so we can't comment on that.