# Subdomain vs Virtual Path discovery by bots

Tags: iis, web-hosting, sub-domain, directory-traversal

I have a website with a URL of lets say "123.example.com" where I am hosting a large ERP system. Does hosting the application at "123.example.com/myapp" provide any layer of security from malicious web crawlers/bots etc?(I'm not concerned about search engines.)

I may be misunderstanding a fundamental directory traversal and how malicious web actors find targets-if so, please educate me.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224560/can-random-subdomain-naming-enhance-security?rq=1

Comment: If you provide a link to it publicly, then where you put it won't matter

Comment: *"Does .... provide any layer of security"* - it might provide *some* layer of security. How effective this layer depends on how easy to guess the path is. And of course if the URL including the path is publicly linked from somewhere else any security gained from an unguessable link is lost. It's basically like a password: the harder to guess the more secure. But if it is published then it does not matter anymore how hard to guess it was.